# rendering two partial views using single model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, partial-views

i am trying to render 2 partial views using same loginmodel:

```
<div id="divLoginPopupContent" class="popupContent">
  <div id="divLPBox"><% Html.RenderPartial("LoginPopup", ViewData["LoginModel"]); %></div>
  <div id="divFBBox"><% Html.RenderPartial("RetrievePassword", ViewData["LoginModel"]); %></div>
</div>
```

and it is giving me an error[image]

and `ViewData["LoginModel"] = new LoginModel();`

can you tell me whats the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely having more than one  `<%@ Control ... >` directives in one of your partials `LoginPopup.ascx` or `RetrievePassword.ascx`. Make sure there is only one control directive.

Answer (score 0):

try strongly typing your view

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<LoginModel>" %>
```

then pass in the model

```
<div><%Html.RenderPartial("LoginPopup",Model) %></div>
<div><%Html.RenderPartial("RetrievePassword",Model) %></div>
```